# No alert of incoming phone call while WhatsApp call in progress

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 7. Lately, incoming phone calls has stopped overriding ongoing WhatsApp call, due to which its only after hanging up a WhatsApp call that I realise that I missed a phone call.

I don't get any audible alert for an incoming phone call when I am on WhatsApp call. There is just a silent notification flashing on screen that there is an incoming phone call. Thus if the iPhone is glued to ear while on WhatsApp call, often normal phone calls are missed as there is no audible or vibration alert.

How do I fix this?